# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1

Tags: flutter, dart

trying to get json from server and put it in a String variable

```
var allData;
var userMapOfInfo;
var url =
      "my url";
  var response1 = await http.get(url);
  try {
    userMapOfInfo = jsonDecode(response1.body); //here i'm sure there is valid json data
    print(userMapOfInfo); 
    allData = response1.body;  //this line cause the error
  } catch (e) {
    return "yok";
  }
```

full exception:

`[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: -1
 #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:147:60)
 #1      List.elementAt (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:356:16)`

Comment: I assume the variable `url` actually contains a URL right? I would place a breakpoint at that try-catch statement and step through it.

Comment: @Benjamin S. yes it has a url and yes i placed breakpoints, getting data from server works fine and Json decoding as well but the exception occurred when I'm trying to put the Json string into allData var

Answer (score 1):

i dont know why android studio show the error in a code line not related to the real error, below the code in the question there was this piece of code

```
var examsLastExamId = 0;
 try {
    var exams = userMapOfInfo['student_exams'];
    if (exams != null)
      examsLastExamId = exams.elementAt(exams.length - 1)['id'];

  } finally{
  print(examsLastExamId);
 }
```

the problem were as follow: exams is not null but it is empty array so it got through my null check if condition, and in this line `examsLastExamId = exams.elementAt(exams.length - 1)['id'];` it through an exception because exams has no data, it was very easy to solve this by correcting the condition to this :

```
        if (exams != null && exams.length > 0)
```

it was not a big deal to correct this code but it is very hard to know where error was when android studio throw the exception in another code line tooooooooo far from the required line